# Xcode autocomplete to show suggestion when "Contains" rather than"Start with"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcode

Being a .Net developer I've vastly worked with Visual Studio and Jetbrains Resharper. 
When using Resharper and VS, autocomplete suggestions appear when suggestions **contains** word being typed rather that **start with**. I've seen similar behavior in Jetbrains AppCode.

[image]

but Xcode, with default settings, just shows suggestion when the suggestions **start with** the word being typed!

[image]

Just wondering if we can somehow modify this behavior to suggest words **containing** rather than **starts with**.

I've looked at `Xcode >> Preferences >> Text Editing`, but couldn't find anything.
P.S. Why I'm not using AppCode if I need this feature? My 30 days trial evaluation is up!

Comment: get a license. Your productivity gain from switching will give you a ROI that measures under one hour.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg,your're right.I think it worth it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question come in first place in search engine, i give a solution for people want this feature:

https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

Answer (score 0):

just go to Xcode organizer and delete Derived data.

Clean Trash.

Restart Xcode.

It will working fine.